# Upper bounds for the expected value

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Let X and Y be discrete random variables defined on the same state space $(\Omega, \mathcal F,\mathcal P)$. Assume that for an arbitrary non-stochastic natural number k, the following relation holds:

$P(X \le a) \le P(Y\le ak)$

My question is if we can safely state that :

$E[\frac{Y}{k}]\le E[X]$

Comment: Does the relationship $P(X\leq a) \leq P(Y\leq ak)$ hold for _all_ real numbers $a$, or only for positive real numbers $a$, or for just one real number $a$?

Comment: I forgot to put this but both random variables are defined over the postivie integers, and the relation holds for any a in the state space.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If $X$ and $Y$ are also non-negative this can be proved easily:  You don't even have to assume that the distributions are discrete. We have the formula $EU=\int_0^{\infty} P(U>t)dt$ for any non-negative random variable $U$. Since $P(X>t) \geq P(\frac Y k >t)$ we get the inequality by integrating w.r.t. $t$.

You should read about 'stochastic ordering'. The given condition is equivalent to the fact that $Eg(\frac Y k) \leq Eg(X)$ for any non-decreasing $g$.

Comment: But since Y is a discrete r.v don't I have to think about the support of Y/k ?